I am not able to apply internal/Inline style on dynamic elements in NextJs
I have a code snippet like this -
<p className="xyz" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: dynamicContent}}></p>

Inside dyanmicContent there is string and one anchor tag and I want to apply some styles on a tag, I am trying this apporach
<style jsx>{`.xyz a {border-bottom: 1px solid;}`}</style>

But this way styles in not getting applied on a tag, am I missing something?

are you using tailwindcss?

No I am not using tailwindcss


Try this, if it works for you
const styleDynamicEle =‘.xyz a { border-bottom: 1px solid; }’; 

<p className="xyz" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: dynamicContent}}></p>

<style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: styleDynamicEle }} />


Good answer harsh keep it work + 1

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
